# Find if the machine is multi homed via Java

Tags: java, networking

Is there an in-built programmatic way to find out if the machine is multi-homed or not? I have the snippet below which can do the task but looks cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

```
int count = 0;
    try {
          InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
          InetAddress[] allMyIps = InetAddress.getAllByName(localhost.getCanonicalHostName());
          if (allMyIps != null && allMyIps.length > 1) {
              for (int i = 0; i < allMyIps.length; i++) {
                  if (allMyIps[i].isLoopbackAddress() == false) count++;
              }
          }
          if (count > 1) System.out.println("Multihomed");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am skeptical about this since all hybrid NIC have a IpV6 and an IPv4 configured on it (at least in windows 7) by default. Hence these come out as an multi homed. Is there an effective way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that "multi-homed" on IPv6 isn't necessarily a clear concept when applied to a host; all IPv6 hosts on the Internet have at least two IP addresses, and it's not unusual for them to have several even on a single uplink.

Comment: Agreed. That's precisely the point here. With this we cannot easily identify if the machine is multi homed.. How ever the code above works just fine... Need suggestions if that can be optimized.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you're not finding out if a host is multihomed. Having multiple IP addresses on an interface isn't the same thing; a machine with a single bound IP address could be multihomed, and vice versa.

Comment: @chrylis How to find that?

Comment: There's no reliable way to tell from a host.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "NetworkInterface" class in java. If there are more than one interfaces other than loopback interface, its multi-homed.

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifs = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
int count = 0;
while (ifs.hasMoreElements()) {
    if (count > 1) {
       break;
    }

    if(!ifs.nextElement().isLoopback()) {
        count++;
    }
 }

 System.out.println(count > 1 ? "Multi-homed" : "Not Multi-homed");
```